# Invalid Page on clicking 'Save and New' button in SFDC Community

Tags: visualforce, community, contact, access

I have one doubt please help me where I'm missing ...

In my contact object, the standard New button is overridden by a Visualforce page.
It is working fine in SFDC Classic.

Now I have a community (Napili) defined in my org.
And this community has Contact List defined. Here on clicking on any one contact opens that contact.Now after opening one Contact and after clicking Edit, the edit layout of contact comes (which is a standard SF layout). On this edit layout, I have three buttons 'Cancel', 'Save and New' and 'Save'.

So on clicking this 'Save and New' button I am getting 'Invalid Page' error.
Also, the URL formed is https://domainName.com/CommunityName/s/CommunityName/003/e?

and nothing after 'e?'.

Note: If I'll put this page on an altogether different section then I'm able to see the content of the page.

I have checked the following permissions
-Contact Object access (It is read, Edit and Create)
-Account has Read access
-FLS for Contact and account is proper.
-VF page and its class is already added in the community profile and Community Site profile
- Also available for lightning checkbox is checked for the page.

So please help me if I am missing something.

Best,
Rumit

Comment: Please check if the redirection through controller action or page is correct after the button is clicked.

Comment: I believe that problem is not with the page as making the page code as 
<apex:page standardController="Contact"></apex:page> 
(No controler or code inside the page) also creates the same problem "Invalid Page".
Also, the page is available if it is added in an altogether different section in Community.

Comment: Did you check if contact create new page(with the url 003/e ) is available in the napili community builder?